# split a scene symmetric

Tags: three.js, symmetry

Is there a way to split it visually in two parts on X,Y or Z direction in a threejs environment.

It should describe the mechanical symmetry, where only on of

two symmetrical halves will be calculated in the further process.

For Explanation maybe the following picture describes my problem.

[image: Example]

Comment: Something like this: [Multiple Views Demo](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html)?

Comment: @zero298 thx, but thast isn´t what i want
It should be in One Panel and i need a visualisation to split the scene in two parts, similar to the pic above